# Opening a new tab will remove session in Chrome And Mozilla Browser but doesn't in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-chrome, mozilla

I've a client code that set session with JavaScript and PHP, however beside logout or session timeout, there's no code calling function to remove session.

On page load(whichever page), it will check for session if no session, it will redirect to login page.

The problem now is in Mozilla or Chrome, after logged-in, when I open in new tab, it will redirect me to the login page, while open in same tab doesn't as session still remains.

However trying on IE and Edge browser, everything is fine.

I'm sorry I can't post clients code. So would just like to hear if anyone have similar issues that can share.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using session storage ??

Comment: Yes, I'm using session storage

Comment: In session storage that happens! try to use cookies or what I did was I created a file to check sessions if the session is active it returns the complete object of session variable and in that way I am able to navigate on pages even on seperate tabs

Answer (score 0):

You will know what page you are on
so set the session
$mypage = $SERVER['REQUESTURI']; // this contains the query string also, you may have to get the values from the $_GET values
$_SESSION[$mypage] = $myDocumentID;

Then on entering the page (tab)
Edit the document where $_SESSION[$mypage] == $mypage and you have the document id

Something like that should work